# Memcached Implementation in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, memcached

I have successfully implemented Memcashe in my appliation
Thanks to [this](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62)
Now I am faceing issue when I try to save cache of more than 1MB size its hard to find out I have already googled some techniques but none of them work for me I am looking for settings in Web.Config file below is my current settings in web.config.

```
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection,Enyim.Caching"/>
    </sectionGroup>
<enyim.com>
    <memcached protocol="Binary">
      <servers>
        <add address="Machine IP" port="11211"></add>
      </servers>
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the maximum size of Item that can be saved in server is 128 MB and it can be set via cmd with command "c:\memcached\memcached.exe" -I 128M